# Odoo 11 : Write method is called in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

Here my code:

```
@api.multi
def _upgrading_balance(self):
    .........
    self.write({
        'balance_initial': new_balance_initial
    })
    .........
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    result = super(InheritedHoranetPackageLine, self).write(vals)
    if vals.get('balance_initial'):
        self._upgrading_balance()

    return result
```

My write methode is called in loop. How make for call once ?

Thanks you

Comment: Your `write()` function is calling the `_upgrading_balance()` function, which is calling the `write()` function. How would you expect it to work?

Comment: My function is long. How to conturn this problem ? I have test 
self.balance_initial = new_balance_initial and this problem persist ..

Comment: To avoid the problem, you can avoid having both of the functions call each other.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple but maybe not the perfect solution is to use the context to decide wether to uprade the balance or not:

```py
@api.multi
def _upgrading_balance(self):
    # things
    self.write({
        'balance_initial': new_balance_initial
    })
    # more things

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    result = super(InheritedHoranetPackageLine, self).write(vals)
    if vals.get('balance_initial') and\
            'balance_upgrade' not in self.env.context:
        self.with_context(balance_upgrade=1)._upgrading_balance()
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a method to contourned. But what do you do with_context exactly ? thanks

Comment: With `with_context` you can manipulate the context dictionary, which can be used to pass data without using method parameters, because the context is bound to the environment. So in this example there is no `balance_upgrade` in the context, because it was never set. But `_upgrade_balance` is called with a manipulation, so the next `write` call will already have `balance_upgrade` in the environment's context.